# WooCommerce How can I show the matching product variation when an attribute filter is selected?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, have an Attribute called Location that contains different areas. Then each product has that Attribute added and it's used for Variations. There is a Variation with a specific price for each Location attribute.

On the Shop (category) page, is there a way to show the matching Variation price on the products when the Location attribute is selected?

**For example:** Product X has a different Variation price for Location 1, Location 2, and Location 3. On the Shop page, I select Location 1, and I see Product X's Variation price for Location 1. When I click on Product X, I want that price set already.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to show the price of the variation that matches the selected Location attribute. I don't want it to show the price range, just the variation price.

Comment: I'm just using the default Elementor theme and WooCommerce. On the Category page, I have it showing the Filter Products by Attribute widget in WooCommerce.

On the Category page, I want to select the Location attribute from that filter widget, and show the matching product variant only.

Comment: Sorry but this is too complicated...

Comment: If it isn't possible with using Attributes, is there another way to accomplish this? Take a look at: https://www.lexarhomes.com/signature-collection-floor-plans/ This is similar in the fact that you choose a location and then see the prices (variations) for that area only.

Comment: Your example is build by a theme maker team called [Edge](https://themeforest.net/user/edge-themes/portfolio). It's build in with one of their themes, it's too complicated to duplicate that, you need an entire development team for that. I'd recommend to consider a related theme from them.

Comment: Thanks @Demian do you know which theme it is?

Comment: @JustinHollender send them an email, the Edge team, and ask them together with the website which one it is. It's a pre-sale question, so they will answer you :)

Comment: I emailed them, but it has nothing to do with the theme